# Number of PFObjects I can pin to the Local Datastore? (iOS)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

In iOS app I'm pinning about 8000-9000 PFObjects. When I restart app and try to load all previously pinned objects, I get only about 5000. In my query I'm not limiting results, I simply need to load all pinned objects in my Class.
Is there any limit for amount of pinned objects? May this possibly be a bug?

UPDATE:
I created testing project where I tried to only download and pin all 9000 objects.
I used proper callbacks for everything.
RESULT:
Pin 9000 objects took 8 minutes, I get a lot memory warnings, the app (bundle has 12MB) gets 300MB of memory.

This seems to be bug in Parse SDK.

Anyone with similar experience?

Comment: Are you pinning them in the background?

Comment: @soulshined Yes, I am.

Comment: I use
[PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) { ... }];